# How can I put a black outline to my text in python?

Tags: python

This is an open-source Reddit post scraper. I would like to add a black outline to the text. How can I do it? I could not figure it out on my own... unfortunately

If this code is not enough , please let me know!

You can check out the entire code here: https://github.com/elebumm/RedditVideoMakerBot

Thank you for any help! I really appreciate it , it would mean a lot to me.

Imagegenerator.py:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw,ImageFont 
import textwrap
import re
def draw_multiple_line_text(image, text, font, text_color,padding):
    '''
    Draw multiline text over given image
    '''
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    Fontperm= font.getsize(text)
    image_width, image_height = image.size
    lines = textwrap.wrap(text, width=15)
    y=(image_height/2)-(((Fontperm[1]+(len(lines)*padding)/len(lines))*len(lines))/2)
    for line in lines:
        line_width, line_height = font.getsize(line)
        draw.text(((image_width - line_width) / 2, y), 
                    line, font=font, fill=text_color)
        y += line_height + padding


def imagemaker(text,
                reddit_obj,
                idx='NoName',
                padding=5
                ):
    id = re.sub(r"[^\w\s-]", "", reddit_obj["thread_id"])
    font=ImageFont.truetype("fonts/inter.ttf", 50)
    Fontperm= font.getsize(text)
    # print(Fontperm[1])
    size=(500,500) 
    
    textcolor=(255, 255, 255)

    image =Image.new('RGBA',size,(0,0,0,0))
    
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    if len(text)>7:
        draw_multiple_line_text(image, text,font, textcolor,padding)
    else:
        draw.text((((image.size[0]-Fontperm[0])/2),((image.size[1]-Fontperm[1])/2)),font=font,text=text,align='center') #(image.size[1]/2)-(Fontperm[1]/2)
    image.save(f'assets/temp/{id}/png/img{idx}.png')
```

Posttextparser.py

```
from typing import Literal


INT_MAX_CHARACTER=50
MAX_CHARACTER=50

#working good
def posttextparser(obj):
    text=obj#["thread_post"]
    newtext=[]
    # for text in text:
    if len(text)>MAX_CHARACTER:
        text2=text.split("\n")
        for dot in text2:
            if len(dot)>MAX_CHARACTER:
                text3=dot.split(".")
                for comma in text3:
                    if len(comma)>MAX_CHARACTER:
                        text4=comma.split(',')
                        newtext.extend(text4)
                    else:
                        newtext.append(comma)
            else:
                newtext.append(dot)
    else:
        newtext.append(text)        
    return remover(newtext)

    
        
def breaker(text,method) :
    
    if type(text)==list:
        lines1=[]
        for lines in text:
            if len(lines)>= MAX_CHARACTER:
                #print('max-detected')
                lines1=lines.split(method)
                lines1=remover(lines1)
                lines1.extend(lines1)
        else:
            return lines1
    elif type(text)==str:
        if len(text)>= MAX_CHARACTER:
                #print('max-detected')
                lines1=text.split(method)                            
                lines1=remover(lines1)
        return lines1

def remover(List):
    lines=List
    lines2=[]
    for item in lines:
        
        if item==' ' :
            lines.remove(item)
        elif item=='' :
            lines.remove(item)
        elif item=='.' :
            lines.remove(item)
        elif item=='..' :
            lines.remove(item)
        elif item=='\n' :
            lines.remove(item)
        elif item==')' :
            lines.remove(item)
    for a in lines:
        if a!='':
            aa=a.strip()
            lines2.append(aa)
            # print(f'"{a}"')
    return lines2
```

Comment: Maybe one way to do that would be to write the text twice? Once in black, in slightly bigger that what you want, and then a second time on top of it, in white. You would need to adjust the positioning of the two texts so they align correctly

Comment: Please consider adding the `python-imaging-library` to draw more relevant attention.